# Well-founded part of a graph

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion

Let (A,R) be a graph. Define by transfinite recursion:

$
W_{0}=\emptyset
\\
W_{\alpha+1}=\{a \in A : ext_{R}(a) \subseteq W_{\alpha +1}\}
\\
W_{\alpha}=\cup_{\beta < \alpha} W_{\beta} \text{if alpha is limit}
$

Show that there exists $\lambda$ such that $W_{\lambda}=W_{\lambda +1}$.

So far, I have been trying to approach this by contradiction.. If no such $\lambda$ exists, then for any ordinal $\alpha$,  there is some $x \in A$ such that $ext_{R}(x)$ is contained in $W_{\alpha}$ but $x \not\in  W_{\alpha}$.

If I find such a  $W_{\lambda}$, it can be shown to be the well-founded part of A. Does anyone have an idea of how to continue from here? 
Any direction would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Show that if $\alpha < \beta$ then $W_\alpha\subseteq W_\beta$.

Therefore, if you let $\delta$ be an ordinal that is larger (cardinality-wise) than $A$ -- such an ordinal exists by Hartogs' theorem, then you can't keep adding *new* elements to $W$ for each step up to $W_\delta$, because there are too many steps for each of them to have an element they add.

Comment: I don’t know whether it was a typo or intentional, but I’d have said ‘larger than $|A|$’. (+1)

Comment: @Brian: Actually I did mean larger than $A$, where "larger" refers to the ordering of sets by cardinality. I'd think "$X$ is larger than $Y$" is a perfectly idiomatic way of expressing "There exists an injection $Y\to X$, but no injection $X\to Y$". Though I can see that it might be confusing to use this wording when one of the sets being compared is already of a kind that comes with a canonical ordering.

Comment: I wasn’t sure. That usage doesn’t really work in my idiolect.